# What should $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)^{0}] $ evaluate to?

Tags: probability, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Please consider $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)^{n-k}]$.

I am considering the expected value of an indicator to the power of $n-k$, particularly when $k=n$. I am concerned about the possibility of $\mathbb{1}_{A}(x)^{n-k} = 0^0$ in terms of whether to define $0^0 \triangleq 1$ but also how this changes the resulting probability (if defined). The indicator alone would point to contributing zero weight, but the assignment of $0^0 \triangleq 1$ would flip that to contributing non-zero weight.

What do I need to consider to resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: Maybe we can define $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A(x)^0] \triangleq Pr(A)$.

Comment: What you define makes sense : the idea is that if $n-k \neq 0$ then $1_A(x)^{n-k} =1_A(x)$, so you want this to be the case even when $n=k$. Naturally, $E[1_A(x)] = Pr(A)$ so consistency is retained.

Comment: Please avoid having subject lines that consist of nothing but MathJax code; it messes up some navigation shortcuts.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the feedback. I have put some regular text to the subject line.